# WhiteStar UML - Automatic Generation of Set/Get Methods

Tags: uml

I just started using the latest version WhiteStar UML - 5.4.7.0 for C++ code generation.

I clicked on Properties and didn't see an option for auto set/get.

How can I automatically generate set/get methods from defined attributes?

Comment: I have answered this question yesterday. You have deleted the question with the answer, obviously. Why are you asking the same thing the second time?

Answer (score 0):

If an attribute is already set as a property, it HAS setter/getter. No need to show them on the diagram. If your tool doesn't generate them in code, it is a bug. Property IS a private field with setter/getter.

Are you sure, they are properties, and not fields?